# Is there any event for after select shipping method in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

when I select shipping method from shipping list on cart page or checkout page I want to remove product vat if it is satisfy my condition for that I was thinking if there is any event like after_shipping_method or something like that then my work would be done but I can't find on net and https://magento.stackexchange.com/ so  I am asking this question.

so what I want to know is below :
for ex : I have 3 shipping methods like

- 1 day delivery : 20$
- 3 day delivery : 10$
- within one week : 5$

so when user select anyone out of these three which event is fired?

And I need some event that is useful for both cart and checkout page.And if there is not any event that is useful for both the pages then what are different events for cart and checkout page respectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the customer chooses one of the shipping methods, there are no events happen in the back-end until the appropriate form is submitted.

Thus, you have the two available options:

1.You can use js, but it’s not good or may be too complicated if you want to do it right.

2.You can use the `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` event and apply changes directly to the quote in the observer before the total will be calculated. Note, that all changes should be applied to exclude your VAT in the collect. In addition, you can pay attention to the `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event, but you should be very careful when applying changes at this step. Both of these events will be called during the recalculation of the totals. Hence, the recalculating will happen each time when the shipping method is applied. In other words, it happens both on the cart page, when estimating after shipping method selection, and on the checkout page after the shipping method selection and proceeding to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, even I was looking for the same and found out this:

`checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method`

Probably, this is the event that you want to observe.

Answer (score 0):

I think their is no any event which gets call after selecting shipping method.

follow the link which list all possible events in magento.

https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

in this list events staring with **checkout_cart_** are the events for cart and checkout page.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What event used to find available shipping method using observer M1? @Ashish