# which event i should call after selecting shipping methods?

Tags: magento2, checkout

i want to write some custom code after selecting shipping method(Free shipping).
I Tried with

> checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method
>
> and
>
> sales_order_place_before

but its not working, can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: let me know can you describe what exact you would like to implement?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I want to call an API after selecting Freeshipping Method or after selecting any shipping method.

Comment: ok what exact you want to do with calling an API? please let me know?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa That API has to take shipping address as parameters and it sholud popup the response of that API. This API is custom API

Comment: No event is fired after selecting shipping method. this will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116279/is-there-any-event-for-after-select-shipping-method-in-magento

Comment: @ManashviBirla , thanks manashvi, but i already went through with the above mentioned link. but i dint found any solution